# Is possible get file in main app from my share extension save file?

Tags: ios, share

**Is possible get save documents file from my share extension?**

I try to build the share extension, the share extension can get the file path. I write a funciton to save the file to my Documents folder.

I need to get the file from my main app. But I found I save the file from share extension path is

`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/9EBF8983-E1DE-49E2-8589-CEE7305EB644/Documents/xxx.png`

I using the main app to get the document path is below

`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CFD67CD9-5A8A-473E-8ECF-FC1C1CF18098/Documents`

the folder id is not same.

Is possible get the file from share extension saved file?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need App Groups. Please read the section *Sharing Data with Your Containing App* in [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Comment: I known using the APP groups can share the some data. But I hope is save the file and get file from my main app.

Comment: Please read again the first paragraph after the section headline in the linked article *...have no direct access to each other’s containers*.

Comment: thanks for response, please look my replay answer, I encounter some problem..:(

Answer (score 5):

You're right. Applications and extensions cannot share *individual directories* due to sandboxing limitations. That's why their directories are different – they're running in different processes.

Nevertheless, **App Groups allow shared *directories***. You can access the App Group's directory by using the NSFileManager like this:

```
let groupPath = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.example.documents")
```

Any target matching the group entitlement will be able to read/write from/to the shared directory (or ***container***). So, they aren't actually part of your application's or extension's process. It might also be interesting to take a look at iOS' [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12), in order to understand the architecture of App Group containers.

As suggested by others, I also highly recommend to read the [App Extension Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) which explains the usage of containers quite well.

Comment: please see my replay question, thank you very much. I try to write some code but not get any file:(

Comment: Thank you @Marcel Voss, I found my problem is using wrong API, and thank you for me some hint and recommend

Answer (score 1):

I try to write the code using objective-c in share extension.

In my share extension :

```
 +(NSURL*)getSharedContainerURLPath
 {
     NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

     NSURL *groupContainerURL = [fm containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP];

     return groupContainerURL;
 }

 -(void) saveFileAction{
       NSString *docPath = [ClassName getSharedContainerURLPath].absoluteString;

     NSString * fileNamePathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self generateMyFileName]];
     NSError *err;
BOOL fileSaveSuccess = [myFileData writeToFile: fileNamePathString
                                               options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
                                                 error:&err];


 }
```

Then my main App to load the folder data code:

```
 NSString * folderPath = [ClassName getSharedContainerURLPath].absoluteString;
 NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]      contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:NULL];
NSLog(@"directoryContent:%@",directoryContent);
```

I found the directory content always got the null.

I had set the APP Groups in the extension and main target.

My share extension save log file path below:

share extension trace log below:

```
 write file success:0 / error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4      "The file “0421_224358.png” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=     {NSFilePath=file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ACDE7845-     E0E3-45C3-893F-6F6978EC3534/0421_224358.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x174251ac0      {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

My Main app trace the folder path below:

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ACDE7845-E0E3-45C3-893F-6F6978EC3534/

I don't known why it save error .

Have anyone can give some hint ? thank you very mch.

Comment: You should add this to your original question, rather than posting this as an answer.

Comment: `absoluteString` is the wrong API to get a file system path from an URL. `path` is the correct one. But I recommend to use always the URL related API: `NSURL * docURL = [ClassName getSharedContainerURLPath]` `NSURL * fileNameURL = [docURL stringBy...` `[myFileData writeToURL:  fileNameURL...`

Comment: Thank you,@vadian. I Try to absoluteString replace path, It is run correct. Thank you , Do you want to add another answer , I can select your answer a best Answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: No thanks, because this solution is actually not related to the question. As already mentioned do not misuse answers to ask subsequent questions. Ask a new question.